# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have a project to display the 7 largest states in America storing each individual state in a variable and displaying it on the page using javascript.

My NEW code looks like this:

```
    <script>
var states = ["Alaska", "Texas", "California", "Montana", "New Mexico", "Arizona", "Nevada"];
var miles = [663267, 268581, 163696, 147042, 121589, 113998, 110561];
var index= "";
text="";
function listStates() {
    for (index=0; index < states.length; index++) {
            text += "<tr><td>" + states[index] ;    
            text += "</td><td>" + miles[index] ;
            text += "</td></tr>";
    }
    return text;
}
</script>
```

And i display it using this one

```
<section id="table">
<table width="307" height="45">
<tr><th width="40">Name</th><th width="65">Size</th></tr>
<script>
<!--
    var result = listStates();
    document.write(result);
//-->
</script>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript uses `+` for string concatenation, not `.`.
You're also re-assigned the `text` variable at the beginning of each loop, so you're only going to get the last result when it return the last value.

```
"<tr><td>Nevada</td><td>110561</td></tr>"
```

Comment: Thank you man much appreciated. I editted my original question to show you my updated code and see if there were any better ways of doing this and more specifically displaying the function and writing it to the document @Aweary

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation in JavaScript uses `+`, not `.`. Try `+`.

Your current code with `.` will try finding a property named `states` from a string object, which is `undefined`. Now the code will find a property named '0' from `undefined`, and it will fail because `undefined` cannot have any property.

Comment: Thank you...forgot about that. Its PHP that uses . as concatenation right?!